# Python: issue with building mock function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, stub

I'm writing unit tests to validate my project functionalities. I need to replace some of the functions with mock function and I thought to use the Python mock library. The implementation I used doesn't seem to work properly though and I don't understand where I'm doing wrong. Here a simplified scenario:

*root/connector.py*

```
from ftp_utils.py import *

def main():
    config = yaml.safe_load("vendor_sftp.yaml")
    downloaded_files = []

    downloaded_files = get_files(config)
    for f in downloaded_files:
      #do something
```

*root/utils/ftp_utils.py*

```
import os
import sys
import pysftp

def get_files(config):
   sftp = pysftp.Connection(config['host'], username=config['username'])
   sftp.chdir(config['remote_dir'])
   down_files = sftp.listdir()
   if down_files is not None:
     for f in down_files:
       sftp.get(f, os.path.join(config['local_dir'], f), preserve_mtime=True)

   return down_files
```

*root/tests/connector_tester.py*

```
import unittest
import mock
import ftp_utils
import connector

def get_mock_files():
  return ['digital_spend.csv', 'tv_spend.csv']

class ConnectorTester(unittest.TestCase)
  @mock.patch('ftp_utils.get_files', side_effect=get_mock_files)
  def test_main_process(self, get_mock_files_function):
    # I want to use a mock version of the get_files function
    connector.main()
```

When I debug my test I expect that the get_files function called inside the main of connector.py is the get_mock_files(), but instead is the ftp_utils.get_files(). What am I doing wrong here? What should I change in my code to properly call the get_mock_file() mock?

Thanks, 
Alessio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems with your scenario:

- `connector.py` cannot import from `ftp_utils.py` that way
- nor can `connector_tester.py`
- as a habit, it is better to have your testing files under the form `test_xxx.py`
- to use `unittest` with patching, see [this example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop)

In general, try to provide working minimal examples so that it is easier for everyone to run your code.

I modified rather heavily your example to make it work, but basically, the problem is that you patch `'ftp_utils.get_files'` while it is not the reference that is actually called inside `connector.main()` but probably rather `'connector.get_files'`.

Here is the modified example's directory:

```
test_connector.py
ftp_utils.py
connector.py
```

test_connector.py:

```
import unittest
import sys
import mock
import connector

def get_mock_files(*args, **kwargs):
   return ['digital_spend.csv', 'tv_spend.csv']

class ConnectorTester(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.patcher = mock.patch('connector.get_files', side_effect=get_mock_files)
      self.patcher.start()

   def test_main_process(self):
      # I want to use a mock version of the get_files function
      connector.main()

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ConnectorTester)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

**NB:** what is called when running `connector.main()` is `'connector.get_files'`

connector.py:

```
from ftp_utils import *

def main():
   config = None
   downloaded_files = []
   downloaded_files = get_files(config)
   for f in downloaded_files:
      print(f)
```

connector/ftp_utils.py unchanged.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  
I've pointed out that was a simplified version, apologise if I didn't specify further. 
Why do we need to write another module (content.py)? This is not very straight forward and requires some work. 

Could you please point out what was wrong in my example?

Comment: As I said, your example cannot work since all the imports are invalid... so I can't really tell you what is wrong...
Basically if you have a version where the imports are correct on your computer, you need to change ``'ftp_utils.get_files'`` to the right path to the function when it is called in ``connector.main()``, probably something like ``connector.ftp_utils.get_files``... But if your folder looks like what you gave in the example, you **really** should consider restructuring!

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to use a complete module, I edited the examples with all the files in the same folder (the fact that you used folder in the example made me think that it was what you had on your computer). The idea to correct the code is just that if you import ``get_files`` inside ``connector.py``, then you need to patch ``'connector.get_files'``.

Comment: Ok, I see the error I'm making now: I had to specify the name of connector instead of ftp_utils. That works for me. Thanks a lot!